# beginner java, showing special characters that correlate to an integer

Tags: java, geometry, character

Doing some homework in my CSC 2310 class and I can't figure out this one problem... it reads:

> Write a program that will draw a right triangle of 100 lines in the
>   following  shape: The first line, print 100 '*', the second line, 99
>   '*’... the last line,  only one '*'. Name the program as
>   PrintTriangle.java.

My code is pretty much blank because I need to figure out how to make the code see that when `i = 100` to print out one hundred asterisks, when `i = 99` print ninety-nine, etc. etc. But this is all i have so far:

```
public class PrintTriangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Print a right triangle made up of *
        // starting at 100 and ending with 1
        int i = 100;
        while (i > 0) {
        // code here that reads i's value and prints out an equal value of *
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

The rest of the assignment was way more difficult than this one which confuses me that I can't figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You clearly need 100 lines as you know. So you need an outer loop that undertakes 100 iterations (as you have). In the body of this loop, you must print `i` `*` characters on a single line, so you just need:

```
for (int j = 0 ; j < i ; j++) System.out.print("*");
System.out.println();  // newline at the end
```

Hence you will have:

```
int i = 100;
while (i > 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
    i--;
}
```

Or equivalently,

```
for (int i = 100 ; i > 0 ; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        System.out.print("*");
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

**EDIT** Using only `while` loops:

```
int i = 100;  // this is our outer loop control variable
while (i > 0) {
    int j = 0;  // this is our inner loop control variable
    while (j < i) {
        System.out.print("*");
        j++;
    }
    System.out.println();
    i--;
}
```

---

So to break it down:

- We have an outer loop that loops from `i = 100` downwards to `i = 1`.
- Inside this outer `while` loop, we have another loop that loops from
  `0` to `i - 1`. So, on the first iteration, this would be from 0-99
  (100 total iterations), then from 0-98 (99 total iterations), then
  from 0-97 (98 total iterations) etc.
- Inside this inner loop, we print a `*` character. But we do this `i`
  times (because it's a loop), so the first time we have 100 `*`s, then 99, then 98 etc. (as
  you can see from the point above).
- Hence, the triangle pattern emerges.

Comment: first of all, it works great- thank you! but i would like to clarify how it works.so your first loop, while i>0 says to run the "for" loop. which is a type of loop we haven't covered in class yet (which makes me wonder why he would give us this assignment, hah) but next you're identifying j as an integer and initializing it at 0... but i don't understand why the rest of that code does what it does... if you wouldn't mind clarifying?

Comment: @EvanLemmons I tried to explain it a little more in the edit above - see if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need two loops, one to determine how many characters to print on each line, and an inner nested loop to determine how many times to print a single character.

The hint is that the inner loop doesn't always count to a fixed number, rather it counts from 1 to (100 - something).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class PrintTriangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       for(int i = 100; i >= 1; i--){

           System.out.print("\n");

           for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
               System.out.print("*");
           }

       }

   }
}
```

Explanation: The nested for loop has a variable named j. j is the amount of times * has been printed. After printing it checks if it is equal to i. i is a variable in the big for loop. i keeps track of how many times a line has been printed. \n means newline.

Answer (score 0):

You could come at it side ways...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(100);
int index = 0;
while (index < 100) {
    sb.append("*");
    index++;
}

index = 0;
while (index < 100) {
    System.out.println(sb);
    sb.deleteCharAt(0);
    index++;
}
```

But I think I prefer the loop with loop approach personally ;)

You could improve the effiency of the first loop by increasing the number of stars you add per loop and reducing the number loops accordingly...

ie, add 2 starts, need 50 loops, add 4, need 25, add 5 need 20, add 10, need 10...

For example

```
while (index < 10) {
    sb.append("**********");
    index++;
}
```